# Ignore pattern inside of a region

Tags: syntax-highlighting, regular-expression, highlight

`:h region` bring me very little help. I need to exclude a pattern inside a region that should be ignored for example: don't apply match/highlight begin from `#` to the end of line `$`
I try to ignore `#.*$` inside a region but seem I can't find anything related from help. Did I miss something from docs?
Or if I need to write a function to do that, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure if that is possible. As a workaround maybe creating a subregion and linking it to for example `Normal` will do the trick?

Answer (score 2):

Create a testing file with the following contents:

```
# foobar

{
    # foo
}

[
    # bar
]
```

### First solution

```
:syn Comment /#.*$/
:syn myRegionWithoutComment start='{' end='}'
:syn myRegionWithComment start='[' end=']' contains=ALL
```

### Second solution

Try `:h syn-skip`.

> skip={skip_pattern} The search pattern that defines text inside
>                   the region where not to look for the end.

See [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way, Even More Advanced Syntax Highlighting](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/47.html) for an example.